# Shortest path generator in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I have graph with a few hundred to few thousands nodes, with weights and its named `G`.

I want to calculate all shortest paths of this graph. To do this, I wrote

```
pathlens = nx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length(G, weight="weight")
```

But due to the size of the dictionary it returns a generator object, so I can't simply do `pathlens[x][y]` to get the shortest path length from `x` to `y`.

I tried to convert it to a dict using `dict(pathlens)` but this operation is taking a long time (at least a few seconds, and it's still going as I write this question). Is there any better way to access shortest paths from this generator?

Comment: So I think the reason that the conversion to a dict is taking a while is because the generator doesn't perform the calculations until you ask for it.  So the actual calculation hasn't happened until `dict(pathlens)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over the generator, something like that:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
P = nx.shortest_path_length(G)
for key, value in P:
  print(key,'-->',value)
```

If you have too much results, convert it to a dictionary will consume too much memory (It makes no sense to do that).  If you want a specific path, pass the source or the destination nodes or both, so the function will will not return a generator [Networkx documentation, see 'Returns'](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html).